# Como utilizar un hilo para llenar una ListView en WPF y visualizar el progreso

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy llenando una `ListView` con una lista de archivos, muestro el nombre del archivo en un `TextBlock` y tengo una `ProgressBar` que debe detenerse cuando termine el `Thread`, pero me provoca la siguiente excepción:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en WindowsBase.dll
>
> Información adicional: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        //...
    }

    private void ThreadToAdd(string p) {
        path = p;
        ruta.Text = string.Format("Agregando desde {0}", p);
        porciento.Text = "";
        list.ItemsSource = fl;
        progress.Value = 0;
        progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
        Thread th = new Thread(delegate() {
            AddToList();
        });
        th.Start();
    }

    public void AddToList() {
        var files = (SearchInDirectory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchInDirectory.SearchWay.AllDirectories));
        int c = 0;
        foreach (var i in files) {
            porciento.Text = string.Format("{0} elementos de {1}", ++c, files.Count());
            fl.Add(new ShellItem(i));
        }
        progress.IsIndeterminate=false;
    }

    private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ThreadToAdd(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
    }
```

Luego probé con Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, pero el programa no responde mientras ejecutaba el método:

```
  private void ThreadToAdd(string p) {
        path = p;
        ruta.Text = string.Format("Agregando desde {0}", p);
        porciento.Text = "";
        list.ItemsSource = fl;
        progress.Value = 0;
        progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Callback(AddToList));
    }

    public void AddToList() {
        var files = (SearchInDirectory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchInDirectory.SearchWay.AllDirectories));
        int c = 0;
        foreach (var i in files) {
            porciento.Text = string.Format("{0} elementos de {1}", ++c, files.Count());
            fl.Add(new ShellItem(i));
        }
        progress.IsIndeterminate=false;
    }

    //Loaded de Window 
    private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ThreadToAdd(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
    }
```

Comment: Yo sigo con mi cruzada personal contra `Thread`, aunque probablemente en este caso no sea totalmente la culpable. No se debe usar esa clase a no ser que se sepa muy bien lo que se hace, es mejor usar otras alternativas mas sencillas y potentes como `BackgroundWorker` o `Task`.

Comment: Lo probé con BackgroundWorker y foncionó perfecto, pero yo estaba explorando otras alternativas, porque en otros casos BackgroundWorker en WPF no me ha funcionado bien, el hecho es que en WForms no pasaba trabajo con el uso de Controles en otro hilo.

Comment: Pues echa un vistazo a `Task` si quieres otra alternativa. `Thread` no esta recomendado. Y por cierto, en winforms es exactamente igual, no se pueden acceder a controles del UI desde otro hilo que no sea el principal

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo de como utilizar Task, es que no conozco mucho sobre él

Comment: Claro, [aqui una pequeña introduccion en ingles](https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/) , [una pregunta en SO con información del progreso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/579895), [un tutorial en español](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) ...

Comment: gracias........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza el [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) de la vista para poder modificar elementos de la vista en otro hilo:

```
//...

foreach (var i in files) {
    porciento.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {
        porciento.Text = string.Format("{0} elementos de {1}", ++c, files.Count());
    }));

    //..
}
```

Comment: no habria que recomendar que use await y task tambien?

Comment: yo probe luego con esto del Dispatcher pero la app se sigue bloqueando