# Error CS1983 El tipo de valor devuelto de un método asincrónico debe ser void, Task, Task

Tags: c#, async-await

```
using HtmlAgilityPack; 
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
public static async string OutputClipboardText()
{
DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            string text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
            return text;
        }
        return false;
}
```

El código es obtener texto del portapapeles  y devolverlo.

usa las referencias ScrapySharp Y HTMLAGILITYPACK

Uso visual studio 2019 community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas `async/await`, debes de especificar que el método retornara `Task` o `Task<TResult>` en su asignatura:

Cambia:

```
public static async string OutputClipboardText()
```

Por:

```
public static async Tas<string> OutputClipboardText()
```

Otro error que tienes es que al final estas retornando un `boolean`, cuando deberia de ser un `Task` de tipo `string`:

Cambia:

```
return false;
```

Por:

```
return await Task<String>.FromResult(String.Empty);
```

Codigo completo:

```
public static async Task<string> OutputClipboardText()
{
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
    
    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        string text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
        return text;
    }
    
    return await Task<String>.FromResult(String.Empty);
}
```

---

Actulizacion 1:

Para asignar el resultado de la operacion, tienes 3 opciones:

1- Marcando al metodo que ejecuta `OutputClipboardText` como `async` y obtienes el resultado utilizando `await`:

```
private async void ObtenerClickboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TxtUrl.Text = await OutputClipboardText();
}
```

2- Utilizando el metodo [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) pero como la ejecucion continua en el contexto del Task creado y no puedes modificar un elemento de la vista a menos que sea en el hilo de la vista, tendras que utilizar el `Dispatcher`. Dale una mirada a esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/121473/38468:

```
 private void ObtenerClickboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    OutputClipboardText().ContinueWith((T)=>{
       System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>{

            // asignas el valor
            TxtUrl.Text = T.Result;
        
        });
    });
 }
```

3 - Accediento directamete al resultado del Task:

```
private void ObtenerClickboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 TxtUrl.Text = OutputClipboardText().Result;
}
```

Pero esta solucion te frisara la vista por el tiempo que el task dure ejecutandose.

Comment: te compilo? estoy haciendolo para la aplicacion universal de windows

Comment: Error CS0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' en 'string'

Comment: Si, me compila perfectamente.

Comment: como la llamas? yo asi             TxtUrl.Text = OutputClipboardText(); y pasa ese error

Comment: Dale una mirada a la respuesta, la acabo de actualizar.

Comment: Ya lo pruebo gracias <3

Comment: Con la opcion 1 funciona exelente 

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `public static async Task<string>`, espero te sirva.